# how can I load one text file corpus using PlaintextCorpusReader Module

Tags: nltk

I can only do something like this:

`from nltk.corpus import PlaintextCorpusReader

> > > corpus_root = '/usr/share/dict' 
> > >       wordlists = PlaintextCorpusReader(corpus_root, '.*')
> > >       wordlists.fileids()`

if i have just a single file as my corpus is there an efficient code to directly choose that file rather than this method, which is for a corpus many text files

Comment: Make a directory and put only 1 file in it?

Comment: yeah thats what i did!

Comment: Why do you need the `PlaintextCorpusReader`? If you just need to tokenize your text, then you can easily do `[word_tokenize(sent) for sent in sent_tokenize(open(filename, 'r').read())]` and that will give you a list of sentences and each sentence is a list of words.